# Ultrasonic range finder with single transducer

Tags: arduino, range-detector

I would like to make an ultrasonic range finder with a single transducer. The reason for only one transducer is because I'm limited in the amount of space I have for what I'm sensing. I've purchased the EZ01 ultrasonic sensor and it works well but I need to make my own now with a waterproof transducer. I have the transducer which is 40kHz but need to put together the other components along with my arduino. I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with this and could direct me to a schematic or any information on how to wire this up and use the one transducer as a transmitter and receiver.

Comment: Sounds a neat project - any ideas what the method used in the EZ01 was to measure range? It could use a radar type ping and quickly switch the transducer over to be a receiver and detect a ping coming back. Or it may be a continuous wave circuit with a sensitive circuit that differentiates reflections from output signals?

Comment: This is do-able however you'll be limited in the minimum range you can detect. The ceramic transducers ring for a while (at the resonant frequency, obviously). The Polaroid [SX-70](https://static.bhphoto.com/images/images500x500/impossible_1513_polaroid_sx_70_sonar_instant_1445970073000_1192986.jpg) used a single electrostatic transducer for sonar ranging (autofocus).

Answer (score 2):

**How do you make a range sensor using one transducer:**

- [EZ01 ultrasonic sensor](https://www.maxbotix.com/documents/LV-MaxSonar-EZ_Datasheet.pdf) is a *42kHz* transducer
- Arduino-based

[image: Datasheet]

As you can see from the EZ01 datasheet, it has the ability to do both. It is the same pinout as my MB7380 sensor:

[image: Same pinout]

---

**How do you waterproof electronic sensors?**

- [How to package a sensor watertight in a DIY environment?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96329/how-to-package-a-sensor-watertight-in-a-diy-environment)

→ silicone heat shrink tubing and waterproof epoxy

There are $13 waterproof ultrasonic sensors on eBay ($15 on Amazon). As Chris Stratton says, the **EZ01 is not designed to work in aquatic environments.** After all, water is 850 times denser than air.

---

**C**

```
unsigned long startMillis;
unsigned long currentMillis;

const byte pinTX = 9; // trigger
const byte pinRX = 10; // echo

void setup() {
  startMillis = millis();  // initial start time

  pinMode(pinTX, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  currentMillis = millis(); // milliseconds since start

  // Reads & returns sound wave traveled in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  // Calculate distance
  distance= duration*0.034/2;  // DO: Change this calculation...

  // From here it depends on how you want to output the data: datalogger, LCD screen, etc.
  // See https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/ultrasonic-sensor-hc-sr04/
}

// Function you probably don't need: 
void read(){ // for connecting to pin 4 on sensor
  int len, m;
  char testStr[] = "R012\r";   // <test> This version takes 1870 bytes
//  in = Serial.read(pinRX);
  len = strlen(testStr);        // <test>
//  len = strlen(in);
return m = atoi(&testStr[len - 3]);  // <test>
//  Serial.println(m);          // <test>
//  m = atoi(&in[len - 3]);     // measured TTL serial output converted

}
```

Comment: You simply cannot waterproof a typical in-air ultrasonic sensor leaving it still working, you must use one designed from the start to be waterproof.

Comment: Maybe he means water resistant or rain proof. Another way is putting the pinout end in a box like I show.